# Why am I getting an empty stack exception?

Tags: java, stack

Please help in this regard, the error is shown as empty stack exception.

### Code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class Stacks {


    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {

        String s[] = {"5 + ) * ( 2",
//                              " 2 + ( - 3 * 5 ) ",
                      "(( 2 + 3 ) * 5 ) * 8 ",
                      "5 * 10 + ( 15 - 20 ) )  - 25",
                      " 5 + ( 5 *  10 + ( 15 - 20 )  - 25 ) * 9"
                     };

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        {

            Arithmetic a = new Arithmetic(s[i]);

            if (a.isBalance())
            {
                System.out.println("Expression " + s[i] + " is balanced\n");
                a.postfixExpression();
                System.out.println("The post fixed expression is " + a.getPostfix());
                a.evaluateRPN();

            }
            else
                System.out.println("Expression is not balanced\n");
        }
    }

    private static class Arithmetic {
        String str = "";

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>(); 
        String postFix = "";
        public Arithmetic(String str) 
        {
           this.str = str;
           this.postFix = postFix;
        }   
    private boolean isBalance() 
    {
         Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
         for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
         {

         if(str.charAt(i) == '(' )
             stack.push(str.charAt(i));
         else if(str.charAt(i) == ')')
         {
             if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(')
                 return false;       
         }  

         }
         return stack.isEmpty();


    }

        private void evaluateRPN() {

        }

        private String getPostfix() {
        return postFix;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
        private void postfixExpression() {
         Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
         for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
           if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
               postFix += " " + str.charAt(i);
           else if(str.charAt(i) == '+' || str.charAt(i) == '-' ||
                   str.charAt(i) == '*' || str.charAt(i) == '/' ||
                   str.charAt(i) == '%' || str.charAt(i) == '(' ||
                   str.charAt(i) == ')' )
           {
           do{
                   stack.push(str.charAt(i));


           }

             while(stack.isEmpty());
           } 



           if(str.charAt(i) == '(' || str.charAt(i) == ')')
           {
               if(str.charAt(i) == '(')
                   stack.push(str.charAt(i));
               else if(str.charAt(i) == ')')
               {
                   do
                   {
                       do{
                            postFix += stack.pop();
                       }while(stack.pop() != ')');
                   }while(!stack.empty());

               }
           }

            if(str.charAt(i) == '+' || str.charAt(i) == '-' ||
                   str.charAt(i) == '*' || str.charAt(i) == '/' )
           {
               if(str.charAt(i) == '+' || str.charAt(i) == '-')
               {
                do{
                   postFix += stack.pop();
                   }while ((stack.pop() != '(') || !stack.empty());
                   postFix += str.charAt(i);
               }
               if(str.charAt(i) == '*' || str.charAt(i) == '/')                  
               {
                   if(stack.pop() == '+' || stack.pop() == '-')
                   {
                       stack.push(str.charAt(i));
                   }
               }
            }
        }
         do{
             postFix += stack.pop();
            }while(!stack.empty());

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace. Please clearly label the line that the exception is coming from. Please post the output of your program. Also consider printing something out every time you push/pop an item, then you will be able to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

When you testing use peek function otherwise you are removing the item. When you do :

```
if(stack.pop() == '+' || stack.pop() == '-')
```

and your stack contains `[*]`

When you call `stack.pop()` you remove `*` and your stack will be empty after that and you will get exception in second test (`stack.pop() == '-'`).

You need to verify your code and change your logic.